# VS Code shows me errors due to local PHP version

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am currently working on a PHP Laravel project. For this project I need at least PHP 8.1, so I have a PHP Docker instance. On my Mac I have php 7.3.24. The project runs as expected. But my IDE (VS Code) gives me an error message in many places due to the local PHP version. For example, the typehint of class variables.

In addition, included libraries are not recognised when I want to initiate them (undefined type).

**My question:** Do I have to upgrade the local PHP version or is there a setting in the IDE?

Comment: If your project requires 8.1 to work properly, then yes you'll need to install 8.1. Your IDE is just for editing the code, it cannot actually _run_ the code directly...that's the PHP engine's job.

Comment: @ADyson Ok. Thank you. I'll see if there's something like nvm for PHP. Do you know something like that?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what nvm is

Comment: If you want to install PHP on your machine you can usually download the relevant binaries from the PHP site. Some operating system provide O/S packages for it (e.g. apt packages in Debian/Ubuntu, or in Windows there's the web platform installer which can assist you. I don't use Macs so I don't know how it works there...some people use "brew" I believe, but not sure)